# How do I record loopback sound in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-8.1, naudio, cscore

I want to record loopback sound in a Windows 8.1 Store App.

Currently I have investigated the following options, but I think they don't work for the given reasons:

- **nAudio & CSCore:** 
  Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Windows.Forms.dll'
- **nAudio.Win8:**
  `WaveFileWriter` and `WasapiLoopbackCapture` are not available.
- **ScreenCapture with only Audio:**
  `Windows.Media.Capture.ScreenCapture.GetForCurrentView()` is available only Windows Phone 8.1 but does not work on Windows 8.1

Does anyone have other suggestions to record loopback sound, or is it impossible to do that?

I would like to hear about possible approaches that could work or any examples.

Comment: NAudio does have `WasapiCaptureRT` which might be able to be tweaked to support loopback capture, but it's not something I've tried

Comment: @MarkHeath Oh I see.It has `WasapiCaptureRT` but in example not working is require microphone and if press record and play it has no sound.

Comment: has it worked out for you? if so, could you please provide an example?